# Sign in with Google works with Azure App Service, but not on Localhost

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, localhost, google-authentication

I successfully set up simple authentication with Google using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google,

It works on my azure site, but not when I try and use my localhost.
I redirect to "/.auth/login/google" and it says "Cannot GET /.auth/login/google"
What could be causing this error?

Comment: Try to add your localhost url in the Redirect URI with suffix `/.auth/login/google` in the active directory and check once

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT where in the active directory do you mean?

Comment: Navigate to Azure Portal=>Active Directory => App Registrations => Owned Applications => Your WebApp => Redirect URIs => Click on Redirect URI => Under Web,Redirect URIs

Comment: Still does not work. Unfortunately it is vey late and I need to go to bed. Thank you for trying to help, I will get back to you in the morning if follow up (when I said it worked, turned out I had accidentally opened up my azure host instead of localhost)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT do you have any ideas what else it could be?

Comment: Add callback at the end of uri `/.auth/login/google/callback`

Comment: `Works with Azure App Service, but not on Localhost.` What does running in localhost exact mean to you?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Callback does not change anything unless it just hasn't kicked in yet. By running on localhost I mean I launch my server file with "node index.js"

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT some guy on discord told me that because I have this screen it means localhost cant/wont ever work for me because i am using easyauth https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/603756071139540992/989931022676267058/unknown.png

Comment: Yes, locahost won't work for you

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you are doing the easy authentication system, the one that that link and its counterparts show, you can't use localhost with it. How one is supposed to develop in such an environment is beyond me, and why this wasn't pointed out in the docs is as well.

If you are reading this because you had the same problem, you may need a new auth system. This sort of thing has happened with the other Microsoft authentication crap I've tried. Ultimately just don't mess with their authentication systems I think. Just don't.